# How are pre-evolutions explained?

Tags: pokemon

From Generation II onwards, several pre-evolutions for certain Pokemon were established (e.g. Pichu is a pre-evolution for Pikachu).  I'm just wondering what the in-universe explanation for this is, as surely when those pokemon bred they would have produced the pre-evolved forms of the pokemon (e.g. if two Pikachus bred they would have produced a Pichu, but Pichu doesn't exist in Generation I!).
**What is the in-universe explanation for pre-evolutions not existing in previous Generations?**

Comment: See http://kotaku.com/pokemons-ridiculous-timeline-explained-in-a-single-ima-1674127110 Fan theory, nothing stated in-universe, but three parallel dimensions.

Comment: In addition to the stated information about breeding being poorly understood in the gen 1 era, it is possible that at the time "baby" pokemon such as pichu and elekid were not considered distinct subspecies, but simply juvinile versions of pikachu and electabuzz respectively, and thus were not recorded in the pokedex as their own entries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of universe, the Generation 1 games, (Red, Blue, Green, Yellow), simply lacked any mechanics for breeding. In-universe, the plot simply doesn't show any pokemon breeding or eggs. And Kanto, the region in Generation 1, has a lower number of pokemon compared to the newer regions. So in-universe for Generation 1, we just don't see any breeding done, all these pokemon are the only ones you see in the wild or trained.

Then Kanto was revisted, in Generation 3 games, remakes actually, FireRed and LeafGreen. Same plot, some updates. You could now breed. Only 3 extra pokemon compared to the originals. None of the baby pokemon, pre-evolutions, are wild. So in-universe, the plot stays the same just showing babies now.

**Essentially, it just wasn't mentioned or seen until a second look at Gen 1 was introduced in Gen 3.**

Answer (score 6):

The in-universe explanation is that they weren't discovered yet. Generation II happens 3 years, canonically, after Generation I. You can get the hint that Pokemon were quite new in Red, Blue and Yellow. Not as new as it was to us when the games came out, but decently new. There were only 151 Pokemon, and Mew had just been discovered recently as it says in the Cinnabar Mansion Journals. Despite there being 151 known types, a lot of them were rare - only one person in that universe at the time had any Dragon-type Pokemon, for example. So, even in Gen 1, there was a lot of things that in-universe wasn't known. In the time between Gen 1 and Gen 2, in-universe, many things were discovered - among them new types, and that Pokemon laid eggs (instead of live births, like how Mew gave birth to Mewtwo). More evidence of this fact is that it's even mentioned in Gen 2 that **nobody has yet seen how they breed**.

Comment: Your last statement that nobody knows how Pokémon breed is supported by Gold and Silver where Professor Elm is *shocked* to find out about a Pokémon egg (although his reaction was much more muted in Heart Gold and Soul Silver, probably because by that point, it was no longer a shock to fans).

Answer (score -1):

I think that maybe there is more pollution in the later generations, which cause some Pokemon to develop more slowly. In B2W2, Magby and Elekid are in the Virbank Complex, which is very polluted. The manga also confirmes that Kanto has little to no pollution

Comment: Hmm. Is there any evidence beyond this?